# Why Mavensmate Does not Work in Multiple Environments?

Tags: security, mavensmate

I want to use Mavensmate as it has a wonderful interface and more features than eclipse. But I am facing problem with opening it at multiple places. I installed it in my office, and now it is not working anywhere else. What should I do to make it work everywhere? Maybe some proxy setting is the problem? Can any one please help me solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by `its not working anywhere else`? Are the OS different? I'm using Mavensmate + Atom at home and at my office and it is working well, but both OS are Windows.

Comment: No. same OS. Did you set up any proxy settings or network setting while install. for me it is working fine at office, but at my home it is not allowing to open.

Comment: No, I didn't had to do anything special. Maybe your home IP isn't yet whitelisted. Did you tried to log in through browser to your organization? Did you remembered to add a security token to your password in Mavensmate?

Comment: I've used MavensMate on multiple computers without any issue at all. Echoing @smukov's question - what specific error are you getting?